# Beginners Python: How do I fix this function check in my code so that it loops back to allowing the player to pick a choice

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I wrote this code for a text-based adventure using Python 3.9. It checks the players answers afterward and keeps them from entering anything other than 1,2, or 3. After the player enters 1,2,or 3 then the code cuts off and does not progress to the rooms that I defined. I tried to figure out what's going on by moving things around, but I kept getting errors. Can anyone tell me why it isn't working? If the player enters K instead of the answer choice it prompts them to enter "1, 2 or 3" then once they enter the correct one it ends the program and does not progress them to the other rooms. I wanted to use the check_function to constantly check throughout the adventure if the player is entering 1, 2, or 3.

```
#KD
#Functions
def start_game():
    player_choice=""
    player_options = ["1", "2", "3"]
    print("Starting dialogue")
    player_choice= str(input ("Enter 1, 2, or 3 to continue"))

    #print ("You chose:" + player_choice)
    if player_choice==player_options [0]:
        room01()
    elif player_choice==player_options [1]:
        room2()
    elif player_choice==player_options [2]:
        room3()
    else:
       check_choice(player_choice, player_options)

def check_choice(player_choice,player_options):
    while player_choice not in player_options:
        print ("---In Start Room")
        player_choice= str(input ("Enter 1, 2, or 3 to continue"))
        continue
        #print()

def room01():
    print("Welcome to room 1")
def room2():
    print("Welcome to room 2")
def room3():
    print("Welcome to room 3")
#main code
start_game()
```

Comment: Could you tell us what's supposed to happen after you put in 1, 2, or 3?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to repeatedly prompt, instead of just ending when they answer the first time. If that's the case, try this:

```
def start_game():
    player_choice=""
    player_options = ["1", "2", "3"]
    print("Starting dialogue")
    while True:
      player_choice= str(input("Enter 1, 2, or 3 to continue: "))
      if player_choice not in player_options:
        break
      if player_choice==player_options[0]:
          room01()
      elif player_choice==player_options[1]:
          room2()
      elif player_choice==player_options[2]:
          room3()
      else:
        check_choice(player_choice, player_options)
```

It'll repeat forever until they enter something that's not one of the options you defined (not 1 2 or 3)

Answer (score 0):

When I copied and pasted the code in my terminal, the welcome message was displayed properly:

```
def room01():
    print("Welcome to room 1")

def room2():
    print("Welcome to room 2")

def room3():
    print("Welcome to room 3")


def start_game():
    player_choice = ""
    player_options = ["1", "2", "3"]
    print("Starting dialogue")
    player_choice = str(input("Enter 1, 2, or 3 to continue"))
    if player_choice == player_options[0]:
        room01()
    elif player_choice == player_options[1]:
        room2()
    elif player_choice == player_options[2]:
        room3()
    else:
        check_choice(player_choice, player_options)

def check_choice(player_choice, player_options):
    while player_choice not in player_options:
        print("---In Start Room")
        player_choice = str(input("Enter 1, 2, or 3 to continue"))
        continue
        # print()



# main code
start_game()
```

**Output**

```
Starting dialogue
Enter 1, 2, or 3 to continue>? 3
Welcome to room 3
```

Are you doing something different in your script?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and your condition and while loop seemed to work just fine. You could maybe add a bit more information like what OS you are using, what editor and terminal you are using and so on.

Only questions that pop to mind are:

- have you installed [Python](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/python.html#:%7E:text=Python%3A%20Version%203.7.,90%20Mb%20of%20disk%20space.) to your machine?
- are you running this from the same .py file?
- what are you using to run this python code?

With a bit more info I am sure we can help! :)

---

**Result from your code on my machine:**

[image]

---

**The condition to prevent any other number is a bit buggy but everything else seems to work**